# Can't figure out a smashing stack segment fault

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, shellcode, stack-smash

I am doing some smashing stack practice recently with the book "shellcoder's handbook".
But when I try to test some code on my Ubuntu11.04 I always get a segment fault.
Here's the situation:

At first I write exit_shellcode.s (just the simple exit(0) function):

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80 <br>
```

then I get the hex code:

```
0x000001b8 0x0000bb00 0x80cd0000
```

After that I make the wack.c:

```
char shellcode[] = "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80";
void f(void)
{
    int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
    (* ret) = (int)shellcode;
}

void main (void)
{
    f();
}
```

> compile: gcc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -o wack wack.c

But segment fault received when I run it.

Here's gdb result:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x080483af <+0>:    push   %ebp
    0x080483b0 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x080483b2 <+3>:    call   0x8048394 <f>
    0x080483b7 <+8>:    pop    %ebp
    0x080483b8 <+9>:    ret
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) disas f
Dump of assembler code for function f:
    0x08048394 <+0>:    push   %ebp
    0x08048395 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x08048397 <+3>:    sub    $0x4,%esp
    0x0804839a <+6>:    lea    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
    0x0804839d <+9>:    add    $0x8,%eax
    0x080483a0 <+12>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
    0x080483a3 <+15>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
    0x080483a6 <+18>:   mov    $0x804a010,%edx
    0x080483ab <+23>:   mov    %edx,(%eax)
    0x080483ad <+25>:   leave
    0x080483ae <+26>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
```

The shellcode array

```
(gdb) x/20x 0x804a010
0x804a010 <shellcode>:  0x000001b8  0x0000bb00  0x80cd0000  0x00000000
```

In f, the ebp and ret=0x080483b7

```
(gdb) x/20x $ebp
0xbffff2c0: 0xbffff2c8  0x080483b7  0xbffff348  0x00145e37
0xbffff2d0: 0x00000001  0xbffff374  0xbffff37c  0x0012e414
0xbffff2e0: 0xffffffff  0x0012cff4  0x08048215  0x00000001
0xbffff2f0: 0xbffff330  0x0011da51  0x0012dad0  0xb7fffb48
0xbffff300: 0x00000001  0x0028cff4  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

After some si, ret=0x0804a010, which is the address of shellcode array.

```
(gdb) x/20x $ebp
0xbffff2c0: 0xbffff2c8  0x0804a010  0xbffff348  0x00145e37
0xbffff2d0: 0x00000001  0xbffff374  0xbffff37c  0x0012e414
0xbffff2e0: 0xffffffff  0x0012cff4  0x08048215  0x00000001
0xbffff2f0: 0xbffff330  0x0011da51  0x0012dad0  0xb7fffb48
0xbffff300: 0x00000001  0x0028cff4  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

Segment fault after some si, which I can't understand.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080483ae in f () at wack.c:8
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Tried to reproduce your problem - the shellcode looks good, I compiled on Debian 6.0.3 using gcc 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8) with exactly the options you used, and in my case everything works perfectly. Have you tried compiling and running this on a different machine?

Comment: I doubt it's this simple but what happens if you use `int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int))` (or whatever size you need).

Comment: No, I just use the Ubuntu 11.04.@Rob

Comment: @twain249: that's not what the OP intends. He wants to overwrite the stack with the address of `shellcode`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis yeah I figured as much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done everything correctly; your issue is that `shellcode` is placed in the `.data` ELF section, and in modern systems `.data` are allocated and placed in non-executable pages. Try this to clear the NX flag:

```
vmuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
vmuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install execstack
vmuser@ubuntu:~$ execstack -s ./wack
vmuser@ubuntu:~$ ./wack
vmuser@ubuntu:~$ echo $?
```

(`execstack` is a tool to query and modify the executable stack flag of ELF binaries)

To further understand the various protection mechanisms in modern OSs, I'd suggest you start [here](http://paulmakowski.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/smashing-the-stack-in-2011/) and perhaps read Mariano Graziano and Andrea Cugliari's paper "[Smashing the stack in 2010](http://www.mgraziano.info/docs/stsi2010.pdf)".